# Database Creation not successful

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to create a Database in android and trying to save two data into it.
My **dataBaseHelper** file is as follows

```
package com.example.imad.sos;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String databaseName = "sostable.db";
    public static final String tableName = "sostable";
    public static final String nameColum = "name";
    public static final String phoneColum = "phonenumber";

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, databaseName, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + tableName +" ( name text primary key,phonenum text)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists "+tableName);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String name, String phone)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(nameColum, name);
        contentValues.put(phoneColum, phone);

        long result = db.insert(tableName, null, contentValues);
        if(result == -1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my **AddContact** activity that tries to insert data into the database:

```
DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
boolean insertSuccess;

String name = txtName.getText().toString();
String phone = txtPhone.getText().toString();

if(name.equals("") || phone.equals("")) {
    Toast.makeText(AddContacts.this, "One of the fields is empty",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    insertSuccess = dataBaseHelper.insertData(name, phone);
    if(insertSuccess == true) {
        Toast.makeText(AddContacts.this, "Insertion Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(AddContacts.this, "Insertion Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

And this is my **manifest** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.imad.sos">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".AddContacts" />
        <activity android:name=".ShowContacts"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Whenever I run the code in **AddContacts** the message saying **Insertion Failed** pops up. I am very new to this and can't find the fault in my code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why using (static public static DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper;) ? Create an object in the activity you want to use the method.

Comment: Use `insertOrThrow()` instead of `insert()` to get a helpful error message about mistyped column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you mismatching column names.

When you create the table using `db.execSQL("create table " + tableName +" ( name text primary key,phonenum text)");`

So the column names will be **name** and **phonenum**.

However, in the insertData method the derived column name will be **phonenumber**.

To resolve this issue you could either

- 1) change `db.execSQL("create table " + tableName +" ( name text primary key,phonenum text)");` to `db.execSQL("create table " + tableName +" ( name text primary key,phonenumber text)");`. (*)*You would then need to either delete the App's Data, uninstall the App or increase the database version (the 4th parameter of `super(context, databaseName, null, 1);`)*.
- 2) change `public static final String phoneColum = "phonenumber";` to `public static final String phoneColum = "phonenum";`

I would recommend that rather than any of the above that you instead always use a single source for column names and change `db.execSQL("create table " + tableName +" ( name text primary key,phonenum text)");` to :-

```
    db.execSQL("create table " + tableName +" (" + nameColum + " text primary key," + phoneColum + " text)");
```

(*)This would need you to either Delete the App's data, uninstall the App or increment the database version number.

---

(*)*The need to delete the App. uninstall it or increase the database version, is because the `onCreate` method is only automatically called if the database doesn't exist. The first two delete the database so cause `onCreate` to be invoked. Increasing the database version causes the `onUpgrade` method to be invoked. Note these 3 methods all result in loss of existing data.*